# Assign an address to a an array list

Tags: solidity

I need to assign an array to a specific address. Something similar to mapping, or maybe mapping ? But i need to list whole array. I need to list every added item for a specific address, but instead only one index i need to list all.

```
mapping(address => address[]) myMapp; 

function add(address _address) external {
    myMapp[msg.sender] = [_address];
}

function getAddress() external view returns (address[] memory) {
    return myMapp[msg.sender];
}
```

in the getAddress function I would like to list all of them(whole array) not just the last one added or index 0.

Comment: your question is unclear, can you give more details, like what exactly is the scenario, a use case, etc

Comment: I would like a specific wallet address to be assigned to its array, and then I can display the entire array for that address. 
For example 
mapping(address => string[]) myMapp

myMapp[msg.sender] = something;

And now I would like for msg.sender to display the entire array, not just index 0 or last added. Is this at all possible ?

Comment: yes, you just described how is that possible, have an array save all the information

Comment: Right, but when i wrote get function of that array it only shows index 0 and the last element added to that array. How to list everything ?

Comment: You should show your written function, then we can correct it.

Comment: Just edited my question.

Comment: Any idea ? :)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `add` function you always assign an array containing the added value instead of appending that element to the existing array.

It should look like this:

```
function add(address _address) external {
    myMapp[msg.sender].push(_address);
}
```

Using the `push` method to make sure you are adding a new element to the array.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Thank you very much